# Xunit - Question about Unit tests without authentication

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I am currently writing the unit tests for my REST-API controller. I noticed that I don't need authentication (JWT token) for the tests as I expected. But if I address the API via the Postman I do. Is this correct or do I have an error in my controller?

**My API-Controller:**

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("persons")]
public class PersonController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly API_DB_Context dbContext;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public PersonController(API_DB_Context context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.dbContext = context;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(long id)
    {
        PersonManager manager = new PersonManager(dbContext, mapper);
        var myTask = Task.Run(() => manager.GetPersonDTO(id));
        PersonDTO person = await myTask;

        if (person == null)
        {
            return NotFound("The Person record couldn't be found.");
        }

        return Ok(person);
    }
}
```

**My Integration Test:**

```
public class PersonControllerIntegrationTests : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IMapper mapper;
    private readonly API_DB_Context context;

    public PersonControllerIntegrationTests()
    {
        var mockMapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfiles());
        });
        mapper = mockMapper.CreateMapper();

        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<API_DB_Context>();

        builder.UseSqlServer($"Server=(local);Database=TestDb_{Guid.NewGuid()};Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true")
                .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);

        context = new API_DB_Context(builder.Options);
        context.Database.Migrate();

        context.Person.AddRange(DbPersonDataRepositories.GetTestPerson());
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(1, "Testuser")]
    [InlineData(2, "John")]
    public async Task TestGetPersonItem(long personID, string expectedName)
    {
        // Arrange
        PersonController controller = new PersonController(context, mapper);

        // Act
        var controllerResponse = await controller.Get(personID);

        // Assert
        var objectResult = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<ObjectResult>(controllerResponse);
        PersonDTO model = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<PersonDTO>(objectResult.Value);
        Assert.Equal(expectedName, model.lastName);
        Assert.Equal(personID, model.id);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

As you can see my unit test doesn't contain any code for authentication. For example creating the JWT token.

Comment: Authorization attributes consumed by web framework (ASP.NET) somewhere in the middleware before controller action are executed. You are testing only the controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is correct. Your testing framework isn’t actually running the Mvc pipeline or invocation code and that, simply put, is the reason you’re not getting authorization errors.

It’s the same reason why you have to specify the action’s parameter and call the method yourself instead of providing a HttpRequestMessage object with the correct url.